# How to find contents of a pdf when launched through button in andorid

Tags: android

I am new to Android.
I have developed a small app which launches pdf files from Asset when a button is pressed.

public class Finish_Center extends AppCompatActivity {

```
PDFView Sample;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Sample);
    Sample = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.Sample);
    Sample.fromAsset("Book1.pdf").load();
```

This loads the pdf. But it does not enable me to search the content.
There is no search icon in the launched pdf. Hence I am not able to use "find" option of pdf.
As the pdf attached are big and used as reference I want to search content.

I tried keeping key pad visibility (To try (pressing Cntrl+F) but since there is no text view, Keypad is not visble.

Can someone suggest a method so that I will be able to search content in the pdf that is launched.

Regards,

Ashay

Answer (score 3):

Use the method indicated below, so that each user may open it using their device's default app (which will probably provide a search feature).

```
File book = new File("path/for/your/Book1.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(book), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I went through the mentioned solution. Despite giving the right path of the pdf the app crashes. Using "Github.bareteksc" dependency renders the pdf to bitmap thus disabling the option of search.  I want to pick the pdf from Asset folder and should be able to search text like in a normal pdf.